# Java: How to use functions of a class which has been instantiated by ArrayList

Tags: java, function, class, arraylist, instance

Here is just a simple example. Obviously there are simpler ways to set everything up within the constructor, but the arrayList I'm actually working with has already been set up, I just need to change individual sections of it. There HAS to be a way to call a class's functions in ArrayList, but for the life of me I can't figure out how.
    import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class ArrayTest{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      //Here's an example of a regular array:
      Length[] lArray = new Length[3];
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            lArray[i].setLength(i + 1);
      }

      //Here's how I was hoping ArrayList would function:
      ArrayList<Length> lList = new ArrayList<Length>(3);
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
          lList[i].setLength(i + 1);
//          --OR--
          lList.setLength(i, i + 1);
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the length class:

```
public class Length{
   private int length;
   Length(){
      length = 0;
   }
   Length(int s){
      length = s;
   }
   public void setLength(int s){
      length = s;
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: See [Oracle Java Tutorial: Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Comment: If you want to call method of length of array list then call like this 
lList.get(index).setLength(i)

Answer (score 2):

You add elements to the ArrayList with `add`.

Since it's an `ArrayList<Length>`, you add `Length` objects:

```
lList.add(new Length());
```

And in your specific loop :

```
  ArrayList<Length> lList = new ArrayList<Length>(3);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      Length l = new Length();
      l.setLength(i+1);
      lList.add(l);
  }
```

BTW, the array initialization is also missing an important initialization :

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        lArray[i] = new Length(); // added
        lArray[i].setLength(i + 1);
  }
```

If the `ArrayList` already contains the elements, and you just want to modify them, you can write something like this:

```
lList.get(i).setLength(i + 1);
```

assuming that the `ArrayList` contains the `i`th element.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! You're not wrong, but I'm actually looking to call the function in the class. Think of the setter containing an algorithm. Would I just have to put the algorithm in the main class or is there a way to do this?

Comment: To call the method of the element in the array, you have to obtain it first. get() does that. Then you have to cast it to the class, so the compiler and jvm know how to look up the method. Explicit casting and generics do that. The answer shows generics in action with ArrayList<Length>. Use whatever class you are actually trying to use as the value inside the angle brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method with your operation/algorithm like

```
public void foo(){
    System.out.println("some algorithm!");
}
```

inside Length class. This will operate on each instance of Length class.

And for iterating, you can use

```
    ArrayList<Length> lList = new ArrayList<Length>(3);
    for (Length l : lList){
        l.foo();
    }
```

This will call everything you code inside foo.